# Question about doing the integral to find the electric potential

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the electric potential which is: $- \int_{a}^{b}  E \cdot dR$.

Assume I am in a constant electric field and I go directly parallel through it across from point A to point B (B being farther away), I get $ E*a - E*b$ and if I traverse the opposite direction ($ - \int_{b}^{a} E \cdot dR$), I'll get the same result because when I go in the opposite direction, I get $ - 
\int_{b}^{a} E \cdot dR$ = $- \int_{b}^{a} -E*dR$. That then reverses the limits and the result turns out to be the same.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is the change from dot to asterisk a typo? If so, where does the extra minus sign come from?

Comment: My question is what my mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, we can express the potential $\Phi(\vec r_2)-\Phi(\vec r_1)$ between $\vec r_2$ and $\vec r_1$ as

$$\Phi(\vec r_2)-\Phi(\vec r_1)=-\int_{\vec r_1}^{\vec r_2}\vec E\cdot d\vec \ell \tag 1$$

Now, suppose that the path from $\vec r_1$ to $\vec r_2$ is given parametrically by

$$\vec r=\vec r(t)$$

where $\vec r_1=\vec r(t=0)$ and $\vec r_2=\vec r(t=1)$.  Then, we can write $(1)$ as

$$\Phi(\vec r(1))-\Phi(\vec r(0))=-\int_0^1 \vec E(\vec r(t))\cdot \frac{d\vec r(t)}{dt}\,dt \tag 2$$

If the path from $\vec r_1$ to $\vec r_2$ is traversed in the opposite direction, then the only change we need to make to $(2)$ is to interchange the limits of integration.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
-\int_1^0 \vec E(\vec r(t))\cdot \frac{d\vec r(t)}{dt}\,dt&=-\left(-\int_0^1 \vec E(\vec r(t))\cdot \frac{d\vec r(t)}{dt}\,dt\right)\\\\
&=-\left(\Phi(\vec r_2)-\Phi(\vec r_1)\right)
\end{align}$$

as expected.

---

Let's now apply $(2)$ to the problem of interest.

Assume without loss of generality that the electric field is given by

$$\vec E=\hat xE_x$$

where $\hat x$ is a unit vector parallel to the $x$ axis and $E_x$ is uniform (i.e., a constant).

**CASE $1$:**
Assume that the direction of the path is aligned in the direction of the electric field.

Let's parameterize the path as $\vec r(t) = \vec r_1+(\vec r_2-\vec r_1)t$, starting at $t=0$ where $\vec r(0)=\vec r_1$ and ending at $t=1$ where $\vec r(1)=\vec r_2$.  Then

$$\vec E(\vec r(t))\cdot \frac{d\vec r(t)}{dt}\,dt=E_x(x_2-x_1)\,dt$$

and $(2)$ becomes

$$\Phi(\vec r_2)-\Phi(\vec r_1)=-E_x(x_2-x_1)$$

**CASE $2$:**

Assume that the direction of the path is aligned in the opposite direction of the electric field.

Using the same parameterized description of the path as in Case $1$, we have $\vec r(t) = \vec r_1+(\vec r_2-\vec r_1)t$.

However, now we start at $t=1$ where $\vec r(1)=\vec r_2$ and end at $t=0$ where $\vec r(1)=\vec r_2$.  We still have

$$\vec E(\vec r(t))\cdot \frac{d\vec r(t)}{dt}\,dt=E_x(x_2-x_1)\,dt$$

but we reverse the limits in $(2)$ and obtain

$$\Phi(\vec r_1)-\Phi(\vec r_2)=E_x(x_2-x_1)$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed response. I suppose I am still somewhat confused. When you parameterize as r(t), how will the dot product work? If time (the parameter) still has a direction, and it is in the opposite direction of the electric field, cos(theta) (from the dot product) will evaluate to be -1, and if it is in the same direction, it will be +1 (concluding with the same problem). How can we determine that the direction of time and that the angle between time and the electric field is always 0 degrees?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  The parameter $t$ does not represent time. It is only a "dummy" parameter and it has been chosen to be such that $0\le t\le 1$, $\vec r(t=0)=\vec r_1$, and $\vec r(t=1)=\vec r_2$.  If the path goes from $\vec r_1$  to $\vec r_2$, then the corresponding limits of integration are from $t=0$ to $t=1$.  And If the path goes from $\vec r_2$  to $\vec r_1$, then the corresponding limits of integration are from $t=1$ to $t=2$.  The inner product of $\vec E$ and $\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$ does not change.

Comment: But the inner product is a dot product right? How would you dot product an arbitrary parameter with the electric field?

Comment: Yes the inner product and dot product are the same.  What is the arbitrary parameter to which you refer?  Here, the inner product under the integral is with the electric field and the vector $\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$.  The latter vector is tangent to the integration path and $\left|\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\right|\,dt$ represents incremental length of the path.

Comment: But the latter vector is going in the opposite direction of the electric field in Case 2, so the dot product should yield one more negative. In Case 1, from 0 to 1 is the direction along with the electric field. In Case 2, 1 to 0 must then be the opposite direction.

Comment: Not true.  The term $\frac{d\vec r}{dt}$ does not change; that is the tangent vector to the curve and already has a directional sense.  To move in the opposite direction we start at $t=1$ and end at $t=0$.  If we were to change both - we get the wrong answer - we would be double counting and end up with $(-1)\times (-1)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
You are wrong in the second integral: the sigh of $\mathbf{E}$ does not change sign, it is always the same field!

Comment: The electric field is in the opposite direction of my path. So because of the dot product, another negative pops out.

Comment: I don't think that my second integral is wrong.